# Menustrip "Standard Items" Code

Tags: c#, menustrip

Is there a standard code for the cut/copy/paste etc. functions that get added when you use the "Insert Standard Items" function for the Menustrip in c#? So that I can add the code to their Click triggers.

Comment: No, there isn't such "standard items".

Comment: @Oded in fact, there is, but it's only for the visual items, there's no code behind it.

Comment: http://www.csharphelper.com/howto_standard_menu_items.png

Answer (score 4):

If you want to copy code from a RichTextBox or TextBox, Put this in:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Copy();
    }
```

If you want to Paste or Cut it, just change the 
    `richTextBox1.Copy();` 
to 
    `richTextBox1.Paste();`
or to change it to Cut
   `richTextBox1.Cut();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I have many textboxes in my form, is there a way to make sure it works on all of them?

Comment: Yes. Instead of making it `richTextBox1.Copy();` make it whatever your textbox is called, for example you could have it like `MyTextBox.Copy();`, or if you want it to cut or paste just do `Paste();` or `Cut();`

Answer (score 3):

this adding of standard items is done via the `System.Design` assembly. there is an internal class called `System.Windows.Forms.Design.StandardMenuStripVerb`, which adds the items. it is very hard coded, so there are no templates which would be accessible.